# How can I limit the size of a widget in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I would like to limit the growth of a GTK text view (controlled by the program, not user) to only the size of its container. When the window resizes, I want it to resize, otherwise I want it to fit where it belongs. It tries to expand horizontally indefinitely instead of wrapping at its current width.

Comment: Have you tried [`gtk_widget_set_size_request`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request)? Along with this packing options for you might be able to achieve what you want. How are you adding text view to the main window?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you posted a short self contained compilable example. You may be talking about the width of the columns in the tree view.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can put your widget into a ScrolledWindow, but beware: this will help only if POLICY is set to `POLICY_AUTOMATIC` or `POLICY_ALWAYS` - then ScrolledWindow will request only a minimal amount of space, required to draw its scrollbars.

If POLICY is `POLICY_NEVER`, ScrolledWindow will request as much size as it child requests, and the toplevel window will grow beyond its normal size. See `gtkscrolledwindow.c`, comment in the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that textview into a scrolledwindow.